# adding value to struct, adding goes wrong in C

Tags: c

I'm new to programming so I'm trying to write a small program were I can show car information but also add cars to my "library"
right now my out come for 1.Show cars looks like this:

```
  ID          BRAND         PICS 
  bbb188     BMW    1   2   3
  AAA-999     VOLVO    4   5   6
  CCC-999     CITROEN    1   2   3
```

but after I add a new car the PICS does not show. 
so if I would add AAA-111 VOLVO 1. this is the outcome:

```
 bbb188     BMW    1   2   3
 AAA-999     VOLVO    4   5   6
 CCC-999     CITROEN    1   2   3
 AAA-111     VOLVO    -398253632   3   3
```

I just get random numbers for pics and always 3 values. 
Could anyone help me with this, and please show me how to do it instead.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#define MAX 1000
#define IDSIZE 20
#define BRANDSIZE 50
#define PICSIZE 10

typedef struct{
  char id[IDSIZE+1];
  char brand[BRANDSIZE+1];
  int *pic;
} Car;


void printCar(Car *pCar,int imagecount)
{
  printf(" %s ",pCar->id);
  printf("    %s ",pCar->brand);
  for(int i=0; i<imagecount; i++){
    printf("   %d",pCar->pic[i]);
  }
  printf("\n");
}

Car initCar(char itsId[],char itsBrand[],int *itsPic, int imagecount)
{
  Car newCar;
  strcpy(newCar.id, itsId);
  strcpy(newCar.brand, itsBrand);
  newCar.pic = itsPic;

  return newCar;
}

void PrintList(Car aLista[],int imagecount, int carcount)
{
  for(int i = 0; i<imagecount; i++)
    printCar(&aLista[i],carcount);
}

void AddCar(Car aList[], int *pAt, Car theCar) 
{
  aList[(*pAt)++]=theCar;    
}

Car NewCar(Car minapatienter[], int patientCount)
{
  Car newCar;

  gets(newCar.id);
  printf("type in  ID \n"); 
  gets(newCar.id); 
  printf("type in brand\n");
  gets(newCar.brand);

  bool imageInputDone = false; 
  int imageCount=0;
  while(imageInputDone == false)
  {
    printf("type in image reference \n");
    int newImage; 
    scanf("%d",&newImage);

    newCar.pic = &newImage; 
    imageCount++;
    printf("vill du \n1.Add another image reference \n2.exit\n");
    int input;
    scanf("%d", &input);
    printf("input: %i\n",input);
    switch(input)
    {
        case 1: 
            printf("Adding one more image\n");
            break;
        case 2: 
            printf("Leaving loop\n");
            imageInputDone = true; 
            break;
        default:
            while (input<1 || input<2)
              ;
            printf("Input correct number\n");
            break;
    }

    return newCar; 
  }
}

int main(void)
{
  int carCount=0;
  int imagecount=0;
  Car myCar[MAX]; 
  int input;

  int test[3]={1,2,3};
  int test2[3]={4,5,6};

  myCar[0]= initCar("bbb188","BMW", test, 3);
  myCar[1] = initCar("AAA-999","VOLVO", test2, 3);
  myCar[2] = initCar("CCC-999", "CITROEN", test,3);

  carCount=3;
  imagecount=3;

  do {
    printf("1. Show cars \n2. Add car \n");
    scanf("%d",&input);
    switch(input)
    {
      case 1:
        printf("ID          BRAND         PICS \n");
        PrintList(myCar,carCount, imagecount);
        break; 
      case 2: 
        AddCar(myCar,&carCount,NewCar(myCar,carCount));
        printf("ID          BRAND         PICS \n");
        PrintList(myCar,carCount, imagecount);
    }    //break; 
  } while (input < '1'|| input < '2');

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. For better readability and attracting more users you should improve the indentation of your code.

Comment: You do not store an image count per car. That's why you get same number of images for every car.

Comment: The `pic` element is an `int *` and not an `int`, which is a bit weird.  You should probably add an image count to the structure.  Note that your `initCar()` function is passed an image count, but doesn't use it.

Comment: `newCar.pic = &newImage;` This will add the same address of the same local variable each time you execute the loop. After `newCar` function is left, the memory address is no longer valid.

Comment: You're using the `gets()` function — don't!  See [Why the `gets()` function is too dangerous to be used — ever!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-dangerous-why-should-it-not-be-used)

Comment: You have lots of issues in your code.  For example, `initCar` doesn't create memory for the pic array.  You need to change it to do something like this: `Car initCar(char itsId[],char itsBrand[],int *itsPic, int imagecount){
                Car newCar;

                strcpy(newCar.id, itsId);
                strcpy(newCar.brand, itsBrand);
                newCar.pic = malloc(imagecount * sizeof (int));
                memcpy(newCar.pic, itsPic, imagecount * sizeof (int));
                return newCar;
}
`  This way you're creating memory for the pic with `malloc`.

Comment: Your loop `while (input<1 || input<2)
              ;` is problematic.  First the condition can be just `while (input < 2)`.  Next, the loop is infinite once entered because the value of `input` never changes.

Answer (score 0):

Your `NewCar` function have some problems. The `newImage` is in stack memory. When you do assignment `newCar.pic = &newImage;` the `newCar.pic` will point to undefined memory region because `newImage` was out of its scope. better way, we just use its value only, don't use address operator here. And one more thing, the `newCar.pic` is an pointer (array of int). So you need to allocate it before use. When you add more image item, you need to reallocate it. And initialize the `pic` to NULL pointer as well.

Here is my modification your `NewCar` function:

```
Car NewCar(Car minapatienter[], int patientCount)
{
    Car newCar;

    gets(newCar.id);
    printf("type in  ID \n"); 
    gets(newCar.id); 
    printf("type in brand\n");
    gets(newCar.brand);
    newCar.pic = NULL;

    bool imageInputDone = false; 
    int imageCount=0;
    while(imageInputDone == false)
    {
      printf("type in image reference \n");
      int newImage; 
      scanf("%d",&newImage);

      // Rellocation
      newCar.pic = realloc(newCar.pic, (imageCount+1)*sizeof(int));
      newCar.pic[imageCount] = newImage; 
      imageCount++;

      printf("vill du \n1.Add another image reference \n2.exit\n");
      int input;
      scanf("%d", &input);
      printf("input: %i\n",input);
      switch(input)
      {
          case 1: 
              printf("Adding one more image\n");
              break;
          case 2: 
              printf("Leaving loop\n");
              imageInputDone = true; 
              break;
          default:
              while (input<1 || input<2)
                ;
              printf("Input correct number\n");
              break;
      }

      return newCar; 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You get the same number of images printed for each car because you only have a global counter. You need a counter per image:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#define MAX       1000
#define IDSIZE    20
#define BRANDSIZE 50
#define PICSIZE   10

typedef struct Car
{
  char  id[IDSIZE+1];
  char  brand[BRANDSIZE+1];
  int  *pic;
  int   imagecount;
} Car;
```

With this change there is no need to pass a count for printing:

```
void printCar(Car *pCar)
{
  printf(" %s ", pCar->id);
  printf("    %s ", pCar->brand);
  for(int i=0; i<pCar->imagecount; i++)
  {
    printf("   %d",pCar->pic[i]);
  }
  printf("\n");
}
```

The counter needs to be stored during initialization:

```
Car initCar(char itsId[], char itsBrand[], int *itsPic, int imagecount)
{
  Car newCar;
  strcpy(newCar.id, itsId);
  strcpy(newCar.brand, itsBrand);
  newCar.pic = itsPic;
  newCar.imagecount = imagecount;

  return newCar;
}
```

When you print your list, you mix up count of images and count of cars:

```
void PrintList(Car aLista[], int imagecount, int carcount)
{
  for(int i = 0; i<imagecount; i++)
    printCar(&aLista[i],carcount);
}
```

This must be:

```
void PrintList(Car aLista[], int carcount)
{
  for (int i = 0; i < carcount; i++)
    printCar(&aLista[i]);
}
```

Adding the car to your array is basically OK, but you might check if you reach `MAX` cars.

```
void AddCar(Car aList[], int *pAt, Car theCar) 
{
  aList[(*pAt)++]=theCar;    
}
```

Now the biggest problem. This function hads issues with memory usage and weird loops.

```
Car NewCar(void)
{
  Car newCar = {0};  // initialze with empty strings and NULL pointers.

  // TODO: Replace gets with fgets!
  // gets(newCar.id); // WHY read before you prompt??
  printf("type in  ID \n"); 
  gets(newCar.id); 
  printf("type in brand\n");
  gets(newCar.brand);

  bool imageInputDone = false; 
  int imageCount=0;

  while(imageInputDone == false)
  {
    printf("type in image reference \n");
    int newImage; 
    scanf("%d",&newImage);

    imageCount++;
    int *newpics = realloc(newCar.pic, (imageCount) * sizeof(int));
    newpics[imageCount-1] = newImage; 
    newCar.pic = newpics;
    // TODO: Check for NULL

    printf("vill du \n1.Add another image reference \n2.exit\n");
    int input;
    scanf("%d", &input);
    printf("input: %i\n",input);
    while (input < 1 || input > 2)
    switch(input)
    {
        case 1: 
            printf("Adding one more image\n");
            break;
        case 2: 
            printf("Leaving loop\n");
            imageInputDone = true; 
            break;
        default:
            printf("Input correct number\n");
            break;
    }

    newCar.imagecount = imageCount;
    return newCar; 
  }
}
```

And finally...

```
int main(void)
{
  int carCount=0;
  Car myCar[MAX]; 
  int input;

  int test[3]  = {1,2,3};
  int test2[3] = {4,5,6};

  myCar[0] = initCar("bbb188", "BMW", test, 3);
  myCar[1] = initCar("AAA-999", "VOLVO", test2, 3);
  myCar[2] = initCar("CCC-999", "CITROEN", test, 3);

  carCount=3;

  do
  {
    printf("1. Show cars \n2. Add car \n");
    scanf("%d", &input);

    switch(input)
    {
      case 1:
        printf("ID          BRAND         PICS \n");
        PrintList(myCar, carCount);
        break; 
      case 2: 
        AddCar(myCar, &carCount, NewCar());
        printf("ID          BRAND         PICS \n");
        PrintList(myCar, carCount);
    }    //break; 
  } while (input < 1 || input > 2); // compare as integers, not characters. Don't use < operator

  return 0;
}
```

The code is not tested. Remaining errors are left for exercise. ;)

Comment: If it really took days, then please regard it as a MUST DO to learn using a debugger. Running your program in GDB or similar should reveal most of the problems in a shorter time. MUCH shorter.